# Advice on a class to represent this xml

Tags: java, xml

I want to represent the following xml into a java object, and the ordering matters for the sub-nodes.

```
<document version="1.1">
<id>abc23423lja123423</id>
<version>
  <revision>23</revision>
  <date>2011/11/28</date>
</version>
<body>
  <title>some title</title>
  <desc>some desc</desc>
  <full>
    <line number="1" count="31" text="some text goes here" />
    <line number="2" count="31" text="some text goes here" />
    <line number="3" count="31" text="some text goes here" />
  </full>
</body>
<author>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <address>
    <city>mississipi</city>
    <country>usa</country>
  </address>
  <meta-data>
    <item key="age">33</item>
    <item key="books">19</item>
    <item key="related>
       <item isbn="2342343242343">some title2</item>
       <item isbn="2312888888">other title3</item>
    </item>
  </meta-data>
</author>
</document>
```

So my class is Document:

```
public class Document {
   String version;
   String id;


}
```

So the sub-items have to be in the same order, meaning the xml nodes in the meta-data node (item) have to be ordered as they appear in the xml file.

How would you design this class?  Using many inner classes or would you do it in a more generic way somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You could have JAXB sort it out for you.  Have it generate classes for you and see how you like what it comes up with; tweak as necessary.

I wouldn't have inner classes.  I'd create classes like `DocumentMetaData`; I don't know what your `<full>` and `<item>` are about, but those would be `List` of classes as well.

Comment: I'm using SAX, and I have to for this.